# How can I fix the width whilst making it look like the div slides in from off screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have animated a side navigation menu so that it appears to slide in from the left of the screen. The animation works as I want it to but I had to set the width of the div to `0px` to make it appear that it slides in from off screen.

If I set the div's width to `200px` it will be 200px wide on screen and then widen to 400px after the animation has finished.

How can I maintain the 200px width of the div but also maintain that fixed width after the animation?

Here's a jfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/kYRbJ/1/

Thanks

Comment: What about moving the container instead of changing its width: http://jsfiddle.net/kYRbJ/4/?

Comment: Why don't you just slide it in from the left instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
nav#cmNav{
position:fixed;top:0;left:0;
left:-200px;
height:100%;
width : 200px;
background-color:#323233;

-moz-box-shadow:    inset  0 0  #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset  0  #000000;
box-shadow:         inset  -10px 0 10px -5px  #000000;

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cmNav").animate({left: 0}, 1000);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kYRbJ/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cmNav").find('*').css('width','200px').end().animate({width: 200}, 1000);
});
```